# Ajax return not passing Data, rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery, coffeescript

okay, I'm sure this is simple but I'm running out of hair to pull out.  I'm posting a ajax request to my controller and trying to get the response in CoffeeScript. I tried moving to pure JS, but didn't make a difference.

the jQuery document implies that my newImage() should be newImage(data) but if i do that i get the error data undefined.  With this code i just get undefined for my alert.

```
jQuery ->
  $('select[data-type=scene]').change ->
  i_num= $(this).attr('data-num').toString()
  i_value= $(this).find(':selected').text()
  request= 'new image for :'+ i_num + ': get :' + i_value  + ': image'
  $.post('/new_image', {request: => request}, newImage())

newImage= (new_url) ->
  alert new_url
```

the controller is providing a response that i can see in the console, but the ajax callback doesn't seem to grab it.
the controller code is .

```
 def new_image
   request= params['request'].split(':')
   @url= get_thumb_url(request[3])
   @img_num= request[1]
   reply= @img_num + '::' + @url
   render json: reply, content_type: 'text/json'
 end
```

the response is 
  3::https://bnacreations.s3.amazonaws.com/g/thumbnails/image.jpg

any suggestions of where i'm off track?

Comment: can you post your controller code

Comment: also are you sure that image in AWS is suposed to be private? i cant seem to access it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This calls the `newImage` function while building the argument list for [`$.post`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/):

```
$.post('/new_image', {request: => request}, newImage())
# --------------------------------- function call --^^
```

If you only want to give `$.post` a reference to a function (which is what you want to do), then leave off the parentheses. Also, `$.post` just wants some data in the second argument whereas `request: => request` has a function as the value for `request`. You probably want this instead:

```
$.post('/new_image', { request: request }, newImage)
```

The [`=>` (fat-arrow)](http://coffeescript.org/#fat-arrow) in CoffeeScript is for defining a bound function, it isn't a Ruby-style hashrocket for building hashes.

BTW, CoffeeScript has Ruby-ish string interpolation so you can say:

```
request = "new image for :#{i_num}: get :#{i_value}: image"
```

Comment: Thank you.  Now i'm back to where I started but better educated.  Post is still not calling the callback.  The response is still sitting in the packet but newImage isn't called. Should there be a separate response package?

Comment: BTW, i'm using Rails 4.0.  And if I put an alert after the post statement, the packet pends until i clear the alert, so things seem to be talking.  Thanks again.

Comment: okay, now I found the answer, Thanks for cleaning up my code so i could search the right place. stackoverflow.com/users/1609186/ivan-fong. I reformatted my reply to render json: {:reply =>reply} , content_type: 'text/json' and all is well. – bobbdelsol 5 mins ago